# uniform continuity problem with open and closed set

Tags: real-analysis

**let say we have a $f: (a,b) \to R   $  is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$
lets show the  f is continuous on [a,b]**

I'm not sure how to approach this question 
since worst case for [a,b] is that a and b is an isolated point 
but even though a,b is the isolated point its continuous 
so  isolated(a) + (a,b) + isolated(b) = continuous + uniform continuous + continuous 
= continuous , I do not think its right... how to approach this?

Comment: uniformly continuous functions map Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences.

Comment: You will need some extra assumptions. Consider a function satisfying $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in (a,b)$ and $f(a) = 213$.

Comment: I believe that you have to show that $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)\neq \infty$ and the same for $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$, since function $g: [a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = 1$ for $x\in (a,b)$ and $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in \{a,b\}$, is uniformly contionuous on $(a,b)$, but it is not continuous on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Kimchi : it would be nice for posterity if you fixed your question as dfeuer indicates.

Answer (score 2):

The actual theorem is that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ then it can be *extended* to a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Indeed Cauchy sequences seem to be the easiest approach, as Deven Ware suggests.

Comment: What is critical here is that $(a,b)$ is dense in $[a,b]$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist The fact that the codomain is complete is also important.

Comment: Yes. That is true.  Note that $Y$ is stipulated to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be dense in a metric space $(X,d)$.

Let $(Y,d')$ be a complete metric space.

Let $f\colon (D,d)\to(Y,d')$ be uniformly continuous.

Let $x\in X$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $D$ with limit $x$, which is therefore a Cauchy sequence by the triangle inequality.

For any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $d(p,q)<\delta$, $d'(f(p),f(q))<\epsilon$. Since $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, there is an $N\in\Bbb N$ such that when $p,q\ge N$, $d(x_p,x_q)<\delta$ and thus $d'(f(p),f(q))<\epsilon$. Therefore $(f(x_n))$ is also a Cauchy sequence. Since $(Y,d')$ is complete, this sequence converges. By interspersing sequences, it's easy to see that all sequences converging to $x$ give the same limit. Let $g$ be the function derived from $f$ in this fashion. We must still show that $g$ is continuous. I believe a somewhat trickier interspersing argument will get the job done, but it't time for me to go home now.